# Regex pattern validation for email in angular forms for multiple conditions

Tags: angular, regex, forms, validation

I am trying to validate email input in angular. The conditions to satisfy are:

1. email should start with an alphabet.
2. upto @ symbol, email can contain alphanumeric characters without any other character.

For first condition, the error message is "Email should start with an alphabet"
For second condition, the error message is "Only alphanumeric characters are allowed"

But I am getting the error messages are displaying at the same time.

[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLac6.png)

//html

```
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="email">Email address</label>
  <input [class.is-invalid] = "email?.invalid && email?.touched" type="email" 
  class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="name@example.com" formControlName="email" 
   required>
  
  <div *ngIf="(email?.invalid && email?.touched) || email?.dirty">
    <small *ngIf="email?.errors?.['required']" class="text-danger">Email is 
     required</small>
    <!--question mark(?) is a safe navigation operator-->
    <small *ngIf="email?.hasError('firstLetter')" class="text-danger">Email should start 
    with an alphabet</small>
    <small *ngIf="email?.hasError('followLetters')" class="text-danger">Only 
    alphanumeric characters are allowed</small>
    </div>
  
    </div>
```

//ts

```
 get email(){
 return this.profileForm.get('email')
 }

 regexValidator(regex: RegExp, error: ValidationErrors): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
      if (!control.value) {
          return null as any;
      }
      const valid = regex.test(control.value);
      return valid ? null : error as any;
      }
      }

      profileForm = new FormGroup({
      event:new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      selectVenue: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]
      ),
      email:new FormControl('', [Validators.required,
      this.regexValidator(new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z]'), {'firstLetter': true}),
      this.regexValidator(new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+$]'), {'followLetters': 
      true})
      ]),
      date:new FormControl('')
      })
```

When I enter a number or any other symbol, first error message should be displayed and if i enter an alphabet, but if i enter any other symbol other than alphanumeric characters before the @ symbol, second error message should be received. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You know there is alraedy an email validator included in angular ? https://angular.io/api/forms/EmailValidator

Comment: You can check if first error is thrown on your second one like this `<small *ngIf="email?.hasError('followLetters') && !email?.hasError('firstLetter')" class="text-danger">Only alphanumeric characters are allowed</small>`

Comment: is your second regex expression is correct? '^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+$]'  I think you added extra square bracket in last  '^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+$'

Comment: yeah, i mistakenly added an extra bracket

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
email: ['', [Validators.pattern("^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$")]],
```